# Implementing 'Endless Page' Javascript following railscast 114

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pagination

I have a simple Twitter mockup set up following rails tutorial and I'm trying to add Endless Page following this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page

Ryan used a products page and index.  However, I have a newsfeed going and so certain variables will need to be replaced.

I've replaced @products with @feed_items but with no luck.  It seems so simple to implement so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**Code Comparison:**

Here is my pages controller which would be Ryan's Product controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @title = "Home"
    if signed_in?
      @micropost = Micropost.new
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    end
  end
```

Ryan's Code:

```
def index
  @products = Product.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
end
```

---

My index.js.rjs (Problem may lie here?)

```
page.insert_html :bottom, :feed_item, :partial => @feed_items
if @feed_items.total_pages > @feed_items.current_page
  page.call 'checkScroll'
else
  page[:loading].hide
end
```

Ryan's Code

```
page.insert_html :bottom, :products, :partial => @products
if @products.total_pages > @products.current_page
   page.call 'checkScroll'
else
   page[:loading].hide
end
```

---

Application_helper.rb (identical to Ryan's)

```
def javascript(*args)
  content_for(:head) { javascript_include_tag(*args) }
end
```

---

_feed.html.erb

```
<% unless @feed_items.empty? %>
<% javascript :defaults, 'endless_page' %>
  <table class="microposts" summary="User microposts">
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/feed_item', :collection => @feed_items %>
  </table>
<% end %>
<p id="loading">Loading more page results...</p>
```

Ryan's index.html.erb

```
<% title "Products" %>
<% javascript :defaults, 'endless_page' %>

<div id="products">
  <%= render :partial => @products %>
</div>
<p id="loading">Loading more page results...</p>
```

---

endless_page.js [identical to Ryan's] (problem may lie here in reference to the /products.js line.  I tried changing to feed.js but with no luck).

```
var currentPage = 1;

function checkScroll() {
  if (nearBottomOfPage()) {
    currentPage++;
    new Ajax.Request('/products.js?page=' + currentPage, {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, method:'get'});
  } else {
    setTimeout("checkScroll()", 250);
  }
}

function nearBottomOfPage() {
  return scrollDistanceFromBottom() < 150;
}

function scrollDistanceFromBottom(argument) {
  return pageHeight() - (window.pageYOffset + self.innerHeight);
}

function pageHeight() {
  return Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight);
}

document.observe('dom:loaded', checkScroll);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty new to rails and trying to do something similar.  but your GET request, for sure needs to go to your controller rather than the one in the tutorial.  maybe you need a render for the .js format in your controller as well?

I think we are going with jquery instead, but I will try this as well today and update you if I find anything.

---update.  i tried this and it worked fine.   i think the tutorial had routes set up as resources.  Thats probably where you got stuck.   Hope it works for you.